# How to configure crawling for existing documents?

Tags: search, crawling

Is it possible to have SharePoint index documents already existing in a local disk in order to display them in search results? That is, without having to "upload" them to the Documents repository in SharePoint itself.
Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

And to follow up on what PirateEric said, here's some handy-dandy instructions:

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1096

Answer (score 0):

Set a content source in search administration in central admin to point to a file share. Make sure the search account has access to the file share and the content should get indexed.